# How to calculate in DataGridView eligibility of a series of cells to be lower or greater of some limits

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'd like to calculate the eligibility of some product's dimensions.
the fourth column of the DataGridView, would be populated by "Suitable" or "Unsuitable" depending on the values ​​(length, width and height) expressed in columns 1, 2, 3 of the same row.

Firstly, I read the data from a CSV file and populate the DGV:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim OpenFileDialog1 = New OpenFileDialog
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim fname As String = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\desktop"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files(*.csv)|*.csv"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        fname = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    txtpathfile.Text = fname
    Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String


    If System.IO.File.Exists(fname) = True Then                         'CARICA CSV
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(txtpathfile.Text, Encoding.ASCII)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ";")
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If


End Sub
```

Then I want to calculate the eligibility of dimensions of all the products, that they have to be lower or equal to 600 (lenght), 400(width) and 600(height).

Example: I have a product (a row) with length = 600, width = 300 and height = 400. The result would be displayed in the fourth column of the same row "Suitable". That have to be done for all the products displayed in the DGV.

I tried to cycle all cells, but I failed. Now I'm trying to calculate at least the selected row, but it doesn't work.

**Someone can help me**?

Here I am:

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim c1 As Integer
    Dim c2 As Integer
    Dim c3 As Integer
    Dim c4 As String


    c1 = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    c2 = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
    c3 = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
    c4 = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value

    **'controll null or empty values**
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(c1) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(c2) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(c3) Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(c1) OrElse Not IsNumeric(c2) OrElse Not IsNumeric(c3) Then Exit Sub

    **'control dimensions**
    If c1 <= 800 And c2 <= 600 And c3 <= 600 Then
        c4 = "Suitable"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you perform this check when you load your data? Also, you need to convert the string values to *numbers* to make a comparison. I suggest you create a DataTable or a class object (you didn't specify whether a User can modify the data), add the parsed values to the Columns and, at the same time, create the value of the 4th Column, to store the results of the comparison (btw, is it `600x300x400` or `800x600x600`? Do you allow a User to change these values or these values are fixed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a datacolumn expression to make your life easy. Here we also use a TextFieldParser to read the CSV:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ofd = New OpenFileDialog

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim ofd = New OpenFileDialog


        ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\desktop"
        ofd.Filter = "CSV files(*.csv)|*.csv"
        If (ofd.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            Return
        End If


        Using csv As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ofd.FileName)
            csv.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            csv.SetDelimiters(",")

            Dim dt As New DataTable()

            'Change the order of these so it is correct
            dt.Columns.Add("Width", GetType(Int32))
            dt.Columns.Add("Height", GetType(Int32))
            dt.Columns.Add("Length", GetType(Int32))

            Dim sdc = dt.Columns.Add("Suitability")
            sdc.Expression = "IIF([Width] <= 800 And [Height] <= 600 And [Length] <= 600, 'Suitable' ,'Unsuitable')"

            Dim line = 0
            While Not csv.EndOfData
                Try
                    line += 1
                    Dim fields = csv.ReadFields()
                    Dim ro = dt.NewRow()
                    ro(0) = Convert.ToInt32(fields(0))
                    ro(1) = Convert.ToInt32(fields(1))
                    ro(2) = Convert.ToInt32(fields(2))
                    dt.Rows.Add(ro)
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                Catch ex as FormatException
                    MsgBox("Some bad data could not be converted to integer, near line " & line & " and it will be skipped")
                End Try
            End While

            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End Using
  End Sub
```

The nuts and bolts of it are:

- Use a TextFieldParser to read your CSV rather than rolling your own
- Use a datatable rather than putting values into the datagridview directly
- Create your columns as INTEGER type, in the datatable
- You can use a datacolumn EXPRESSION to calculate suitability - it will automatically set the value of the datatable column based on the values in the other columns.
- You can even update the gridview by typing into it and the last column will automatically change from Suitable/Unsuitable depending

Consider also that width/height/length are reasonably relative (unless the package MUST be a certain way up) so it seems cruel to reject a package that has been entered as 600x600x800 when turning it over means it would be 800x600x600 and therefore acceptable, so consider SORTING the sizes before you assign them so the largest dimension is in the first column:

```
        While Not csv.EndOfData
            Try
                Dim fields = csv.ReadFields()

                Dim sizes(2) as Integer
                For i as Integer = 0 to 2 
                  sizes(i) = Convert.ToInt32(fields(i))
                Next i
                Array.Sort(sizes)

                Dim ro = dt.NewRow()
                ro(0) = sizes(2) 'the largest after sorting
                ro(1) = sizes(1)
                ro(2) = sizes(0)
                dt.Rows.Add(ro)

            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
```

Other points:

- I don't know for sure which column in your CSV is width/height/length, but maybe it doesn't matter
- Please rename your components after you drop them on a form. Nothing is more difficult than trying to help someone who has written a large form with 50 labels and 50 textfields and 20 buttons all called Label1..50, TextBox1..50 etc. Renaming takes seconds and makes your code make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make the DGV set the values of the fourth column for you by handling the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8) event, so you don't need to do that manually by clicking that button.

Assuming the indexes of the `Length`, `Width`, and `Height` columns are `0, 1, 2` respectively and we need to set the values of index `3`.

```vb
'...
'Declare variables for the max values allowed...
Private ReadOnly MaxLength As Integer = 600
Private ReadOnly MaxWidth As Integer = 400
Private ReadOnly MaxHeight As Integer = 600
'...

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    Dim s = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim length, width, height As Integer

    If e.RowIndex > -1 AndAlso
        Not Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Any(Function(i) s(i, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing) AndAlso
        Integer.TryParse(s(0, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString, length) AndAlso
        Integer.TryParse(s(1, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString, width) AndAlso
        Integer.TryParse(s(2, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString, height) Then
        s(3, e.RowIndex).Value = If(length <= MaxLength AndAlso width <= MaxWidth AndAlso height <= MaxHeight,
                "Suitable", "Unsuitable")
    End If

End Sub
```

That's it all.

However, and for any unknown reasons you need to do that manually through a button click, then you need to handle the `Click` event as follows:

```vb
Dim dgv = DataGridView1
Dim length, width, height As Integer

For Each r In dgv.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
Where(Function(x) Not Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Any(Function(i) x.Cells(i).Value Is Nothing))

    If Integer.TryParse(r.Cells(0).Value.ToString, length) AndAlso
    Integer.TryParse(r.Cells(1).Value.ToString, width) AndAlso
    Integer.TryParse(r.Cells(2).Value.ToString, height) Then
        r.Cells(3).Value = If(length <= MaxLength AndAlso width <= MaxWidth AndAlso height <= MaxHeight,
            "Suitable", "Unsuitable")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks you very much for the solution. But i'd like within your code solution the possibility to order the dimensions of the item from the bigger to the smaller dimension as @Caius Jard suggests.

Comment: @GabrieleLanati No, what you want has nothing to do with this code. You need to sort the entries when you read them from the `csv` file.